# ASP.NET FileUpload: how to automatically post back once a file is selected?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a ASP.NET app and i have a need to post back to the server after a file is chosen in a FileUpload control without having to have the user explicitly click a 'submit' button. Is this possible? and if so, how?

Comment: A clear question with two good answers closed after four and a half years?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to make the upload start right away. If so, you should react to the `change` event in JavaScript, and simply make it submit the form.

```
<!-- HTML code --->
<input 
  type="file" 
  onchange="if (confirm('Upload ' + this.value + '?')) this.form.submit();"
>
```

Asking the users for confirmation is recommendable, so they stay in control of the process and can cancel if they chose the wrong file by accident.

Comment: Definitely give the user an opportunity to abort if they suddenly realize that they clicked on the wrong file.

Answer (score 17):

The first answer had the right javascript, but ASP.NET does not necessarily expose the input control directly, so it is better to put the onchange event on the FileUpload control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="myFileUpload" onchange="if (confirm('Upload ' + this.value + '?')) this.form.submit();" runat="server" />
```

Another route to go is to provide rich uploading via flash/silverlight/ajax.  A great component for this can be found at [Ajax Uploader](http://www.ajaxuploader.com/) for about $100