# ASP - file upload in single step

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

Browse and Upload with using `asp:FileUpload`control is working perfectly fine.
But It is two step process. First we have to browse and then select the file. 
I want it working in single step So for making it single step I tried the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //to launch the hidden fileupload dialog
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript (GetType(),
"hwa", "document.getElementById('fileupload').click();", true);

    //Getting the file name
    if (this.fileupload.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = this.fileupload.FileName;

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "alert('Selected File: '" + filename + ");", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "alert('No FILE has been selected');", true);
    }

}
```

In this code, there is one `fileUpload` control that is being invoked on `Button1_Click`. 
Ideally it should execute the first line then A file Upload control should be shown and after selecting a file or canceling the dialog, flow should go to next line. But dialog is showing up after full function execution finishes. 
Because of this asynchronous or not expected execution flow `if (this.fileupload.HasFile)` is returning false(because user has not been asked to select any file yet) and I am not getting the selected file name.
Can we modify this code to achieve file upload in single step? Or if any other way is possible to do this?

**Note-** I have asked not to use `window forms` and `Threads`. So solution by using these two is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact there is a client side/server side disconnect in the web environment.

Your line: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript (GetType(),"hwa","document.getElementById('fileupload').click();", true);` is client side code and will not be executed until the serverside script is comleted and the resulting HTML/javascript/CSS returned to the browser as it is client side javascript. YOu want to be leveraging the `onchange` event of the file upload control.

The question should help you out: [ASP.NET FileUpload: how to automatically post back once a file is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366631/asp-net-fileupload-how-to-automatically-post-back-once-a-file-is-selected)

Answer (score 1):

this is not exactly what you are looking for but it does what you want. difference is that instead of clicking a separate button you have to click the `Browse` button. and when you press the `Open` button, the page will postback. I have used JQuery for this. here's my code

**ASPX**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="upload" style="display:none" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isfirst = true;
        $(function () {

            $('#<%= fileupload1.ClientID %>').on('change', function (e) {
                console.log('change triggered');
                $('#<%= btn.ClientID%>').trigger('click'); // trigger the btn button click which i have hidden using style='display:none'
            });
        });

    </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO 
}
```

Comment: ('#<%= fileupload1.ClientID %>').on('change', function (e) this line is giving error that "On" function is not defined

Comment: which version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js

Comment: use a latest version. jquery.1.9.1 is the latest

Comment: i updated and its working in normal scenario. I am invoking fileupload with other button so when fileUpload is getting invoked with clicking on other button, ur jquery code is not working.

Comment: @USER_NAME : i tried with a separate button too. in my case i was only able to invoke the browse button. but wasn't able to postback the page when `open` was clicked.

Comment: so any solution for this problem??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27828/discussion-between-user-name-and-th1rdey3)

Comment: I can't come to chat. I am still trying to figure out a solution. If I can find any, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who land here late,

```
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fu" runat="server"  CssClass="bbbb" onchange="clickSeverControl()"/>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Upload" ID="lnkUpload" runat="server" OnClientClick="showUpload();return false;" OnClick="lnkUpload_Click"/>
    </div>
```

hide the file control with css

```
    <style>
    .hiddenStyle {
        visibility:hidden;            
    }
    </style>
```

on client click event of link button trigger the click of file upload control

```
    function showUpload() {
        document.getElementById("fu").click();
    }
```

on change event trigger the server side click

```
    function clickSeverControl() {

        __doPostBack('<%= lnkUpload.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');
    }
```

on server click save the uploaded file

```
    protected void lnkUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fu.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload") + "/" + fu.PostedFile.FileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the other answer I have just combine two example and got the solution for my problem in my project

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnUploadBulk" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="upload" style="display:none" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isfirst = true;
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= btnUploadBulk.ClientID%>').on('click', function (e) {
            showUpload();
        })
        });
    function showUpload() {
        var control = document.getElementById("<%= FileUploadControl.ClientID %>");
        control.click();
    }

</script>
</form>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO 
}
```

This worked for me